# Legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand how to change the title and labels in the legend when using ggplot2 in R. I have searched online trying to find the answer, and it seems like I need to use the `scale_xxx_yyy` command in some way, but I can't seem to get it right. A simple example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)

dens1 <- density(x, 0.1, kernel = "rectangular")
dens2 <- density(x, 0.1, kernel = "gaussian")

df <- data.frame(x = dens1$x, y1 = dens1$y, y2 = dens2$y)

pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_line(aes(y=y1, colour = "y1")) + geom_line(aes(y=y2, colour = "y2"))
pl + scale_fill_discrete(name="Kernels", breaks=c("y1", "y2"), labels=c("Rectangular", "Gaussian"))
```

I want the legend to have title "Kernels" and labels "Rectangular" and "Gaussian", but nothing happens. I have also tried `scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Kernels")` and `labs(linetype="Kernels")` as suggested elsewhere, buit still nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `scale_color_discrete` instead.

Comment: I would suggest searching web for keywords "ggplot2 cookbook". Very good material that will help you along the way.

Comment: @Pascal That fixed it. I tried most of the combinations, but apparently not this one.

Comment: @A.Val. That's where I looked and found out about these `scale_xxx_yyy` commands. But when I tried what they used on my plot, it didn't work, and hence my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. As @Pascal said, `scale_color_discrete` is the one for you. I guess the more you us ggplot2, the more you get used to the scale_xxx_yyy business. The cookbook suggested by @A.Val is a great book. Here is [the link](http://www.cookbook-r.com) for you

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = dens1$x, y1 = dens1$y, y2 = dens2$y) %>%
      gather(variable, value, - x)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
geom_line() +
scale_color_discrete(name = "Kernels", breaks=c("y1", "y2"), labels =c("Rectangular", "Gaussian"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks just as I want it! I can't produce it myself, however, due to the %<% operator. Do I need additional packages to be loaded?

Comment: @hejseb Ah sorry. I  revised my suggestion.